# HLA Starter Kit Examples

Tags: simulation, high-level-architecture

I test examples from [HLA Starter Kit](http://www.pitch.se/hlatutorial) by using Eclipse and Pitch pRTI Free. For fuelEconomy example, carsimj, simulationanager and mapviewer start normally.

But simulation manager has only these commands

Select a command

```
1: Start simulating
2: Stop simulating
Q: Quit the Master Federate
```

It doesn’t include all command. And also mapviewer is no scenario loaded.

What should I do? Please advise me.

Comment: I've changed the tag, since the `hla` tag refers to High Level Assembly, not High Level Architecture (simulation)

Comment: Got problem to run HLA starter Kit on W10 : `Could not connect to CRC.
hla.rti1516e.exceptions.ConnectionFailed: Failed to connect to CRC at '/192.168.56.1:8989'. Check address and make sure that CRC is running.` pRTI is running. Any clue (not found googling) ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the instructions from **Lab D-1: A first test run of the federation** in the HLA Tutorial.

When I start the Simulation Manager federate I get the following messages on the console:

```
Welcome to the Master Federate of the Fuel Economy Federation
Make sure that your desired federates have joined the federation!

Select a command
1. Load the cupertino scenario
2. Load the redmond scenario
3. Start simulating
4. Stop simulating
Q. Quit the Master Federate
>
```

Make sure that `Simulation.config` can be found in the current working directory, and that the `scenarioDir` in the config file points to the root `scenario` directory.

#### My Installation

My `Simulation.config` looks like this:

```
localSettingsDesignator=Tutorial
federationName=HLA Tutorial
federateName=Master

scenarioDir=../../../scenario
fom=../../../fom/FuelEconomyBase.xml
```

The `scenario` dir contains the following files:

```
cupertino.png
cupertino.scenario
redmond.png
redmond.scenario
```

Answer (score -3):

I dont use eclipse at all.
But from my personal experience I advice you to try HIDE.
You can download it fron here https://sites.google.com/site/highlevelassembly/downloads/hide

Hope I helped :)

Comment: This question is about the distributed simulations standard High Level Architecture (HLA).